# Reading Multiple Files from IFS

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I have a IFS file location where I have multiple inbound files from external system. There are Item related files which has a naming of `ITEM_DDMMYYHHMMSS` and customer related files as `CUST_DDMMYYHHMMSS`.
There would be multiple files and my Item program has to read the Item file one by one and my customer program has to read the customer files one by one.
I dont think a Mere CPYFRMIMPF can achieve this. Is there a good way to achieve this?

Comment: There are a multitude of way to handle this.  You also mention that you have existing programs.  Can you give some more details on what you are looking for?  This is tagged ibm-midrange only.  Are you attempting this in RPG, COBOL, CL, C, Java, Python, some other language?  Are these possibly CSV files?  Do you just want to put the data into a table somewhere or are you looking for some specific processing on them?

Comment: Hi, I will be using CL and SQLRPGLE. This would be an .xml file(in the IFS). I need to put them in different tables(Using XML table). Can You please advise what would be the best way?

Comment: I have posted an answer below.  In the meantime, can you please add the relevant language tags to this question?

Comment: @Player1st - Unfortunately, the tag situation surrounding the IBM midrange platform leaves a lot to be desired. So adding "relevant language tags" is easier said than done. On the bright side, CL and RPG and their variants are pretty much the *de facto* standard languages of the platform, so just being tagged ibm-midrange already gets you most of the way there.

Comment: Player1st brings up a good point about the multitude of possible languages. If you are open to using other languages, there are better choices available. In particular, Python and Node.js (JavaScript) are the big-name languages now available on the platform. Generally speaking, almost any PASE language will be better at working with IFS stream files than the traditional, QSYS-based languages.

Comment: @JohnY Yes there is definitely an issue with language tags on StackOverflow however I know at least the RPGLE tag exists.  Thank you for tagging it with that at least.  In regards to your second comment, I absolutely agree that the PASE languages are going to be able to handle the IFS processing better.  In turn though, they also tend to handle the database interface to DB2 worse so you end up working around something either way.

Comment: @Player1st - In my opinion, the PASE languages are better at database access than the ILE languages are at IFS access, because the PASE languages all use SQL. RPG will always have a performance advantage, but unless you are a die-hard RLA coder, modern dynamic languages are *at least* as easy to use as SQLRPGLE. (And if you are willing to use the QSYS-based iSeriesPython, you actually get RLA, SQL, and IFS handling all in one super-easy-to-use package.)

Comment: @JohnY They all use SQL but you still have to setup the DB2 connection which I'll admit is not particularly difficult.  However, I don't find the IFS handling in RPG particularly difficult either since I came from a C language background.  More importantly, we are getting way off topic here. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I happen to have resolved pretty much this exact situation about a year ago.  Scott's answer to use the C apis from RPG is a good answer.  However if you happen to have TAATOOLS on your system, it has a command called `CVTIFS` that makes this even easier (http://www.taatool.com/document/L_cvtifs.html).  It's a fairly common third party tool so hopefully its available.  You solution then becomes something like the following:

```
   // CVTIFS OBJ(MyDirectory) OUTLIB(QTEMP) PROCSUBDIR(*NO) <-- Call this however you prefer

   Exec Sql Declare FileNames Cursor For
       Select IfDirE From QTemp.IfsDirP
       Where IfoTyp = '*STMF' And IfPDir = :MyDirectory;

   Exec Sql Open FileNames;

   Exec Sql Fetch FilesNames Into :FileName;
   DoW SqlState = '00000';
       // Run your SQL XMLTable command here using FileName
       Exec Sql Fetch FilesNames Into :FileName;
   EndDo;

   Exec Sql Close FileNames;
```

Additional note: You could also combine all of this into one large SQL statement and avoid the cursor but this is probably easier to understand as an answer.

Comment: This is Perfect for me. I tried this out and it worked like a Beauty. THanks a lot for this solution!

Answer (score 4):

You will need to read all the files of interest in a program and then loop through them and process individually.  You can use Scott Klement's tutorial on using the IFS with RPG.

http://www.scottklement.com/presentations/#RPGIFS

It has examples of reading a list of files in a directory.  Then process as needed.